# Java application double tap won't work when running it in Windows 8 tablet

Tags: java, windows

I've created a java application that works well on desktops with Windows7 OS. 
I tried to run the program on a Windows 8 environment. The device I use is a tablet.
The java application was installed and indeed run. But the issue is regarding the double tapping. That program has something like when you double click and item to select. 
But in the tablet, you will have to double tap that one. But double tapping the item will do nothing. It will only highlight though in first click, but when double tapping it, nothing.
What could be the issue in Windows 8 tablets regarding this one. 
Does this have something to do with java in Windows 8?

Any idea is greatly appreciated. Thanks

[UPDATE:]
event code:

```
    private void jListItemsMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                           
        System.out.println("Product Clicked 1");
        if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {

            m_ReturnProduct = (ItemsInfo) jListItems.getSelectedValue();
            if (m_ReturnProduct != null) {
                buttonTransition(m_ReturnProduct);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: to what event are you listening?

Comment: mouseclicked event. so, that event won't work in windows 8 tablets?

Comment: mouseclicked event for double tap? it seems like you're just having luck that it works on windows 7. are you using MouseEvent.getClickCount() in your method? maybe it'll help us if you show us some code of the listener

Comment: yes, it was originally deployed in windows 7-desktop. but on windows8 tablet..nothing. i'll update my post to include my code of the event

Comment: i guess on windows 8 you run in the method 2 times, both with clickcount = 1 that's why there is nothing executed. can you try i that is true? if so: i may have workaround

Comment: i cannot verify it on my on since i don't hava a windows 8 tablet

Comment: i tried changing the condition instead of if(evt.getClickCount == 2) i changed it to 1..and it work. but i wonder why i didnt not work with two.. what's your workaround?

Comment: how can i implement a double click on this one?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36855/discussion-between-sftdev-and-philipp-sander)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears, that Windows 8 Tablet has a low MultiClickInterval.

You can get that value with this line:
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("awt.multiClickInterval")

My workaround is, that you code your own MultiClickInterval with Timer and TimerTask:

You need a static `Map<java.awt.Component, Integer>` that holds the click count for each `Component`.

```
public static final Map<java.awt.Component, Integer> MULTI_CLICK_MAP = new HashMap<java.awt.Component, Integer>();
```

You also need a `java.util.Timer`

```
private Timer timer = new Timer();
```

In the Method you increase the counter for the component. When it's 2 you execute the code.
A TimerTask will reset the counter after a defined time.

Your method will look like this:

```
private void jListItemsMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) { 
    Component comp = evt.getComponent();

    //added the component to the map or increase the counter
    if(MULTI_CLICK_MAP.containsKey(comp)) {
        MULTI_CLICK_MAP.put(comp, 1);
    } else {
        int oldCounter = MULTI_CLICK_MAP.get(comp);

        MULTI_CLICK_MAP.put(comp, oldCounter + 1);
    }

    //check for double click
    if (MULTI_CLICK_MAP.get(comp) == 2) {
        MULTI_CLICK_MAP.remove(comp);

        //here is your logic
        m_ReturnProduct = (ItemsInfo) jListItems.getSelectedValue();
        if (m_ReturnProduct != null) {
            buttonTransition(m_ReturnProduct);
        }
    } 
    else {

        //start the TimerTask that resets the counter. this will reset after 1 second (1000 milliseconds)
        this.timer.schedule(new ClickReseter(comp), 1000);
    }

}
```

The ClickReset is a simple TimerTask that holds the `Component`

```
public class ClickReseter extends TimerTask {

    private Component component;

    public ClickReseter(Component component)
    {
        this.component = component;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        MULTI_CLICK_MAP.remove(component);

    }

}
```

**I hope this works out for you. It didn't test it! if you have any questions, feel free to ask.**

Comment: im confused as to what `timer` is?